# Difference of Borel set and non-Borel set

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are Lebesgue measurable. Suppose $A$ is Borel measurable but that $B$ is not. True or false: $A - B$ is uncountable.

I had a proof written up, but mine assumed that $B \subseteq A$, which need not be true. Now I'm stuck!!

Comment: I also thought about mapping $B$ into a measurable set under a measurable function, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Let $C$ be a non-Borel set which does not intersect $A$ and let $B = A \cup C$.  What is $A - B$?

Comment: Oh $A - B = \varnothing$, which is countable. Too easy. Good idea. Thank you!